# Text and box drop shadow, rounded corners and gradients with jQuery official plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gradient, rounded-corners, shadow

Is there any official jQuery plugin (like jQuery UI) that allows those effects in all browsers? Or at least IE8, Chome, FF and Opera. I don't want user plugins as those often lack support in the long term, are uncompatible with one another or lack consistent quality and optimization.

I saw some "Overlay and Shadow Classes" in the jQuery UI demo page, but I cannot find any documentation on them. I think that those so often desired features must be included in jQuery somehow?

I will appretiate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: well i really doubt it, as IE8 doesn't support CSS3 shadows...

Comment: Well, that is the point, IE8 does not support shadows. Nor any of the other effects I mention. But they can be emulated in different ways. Including jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "official" way to do it, but there is a pragmatic way (which has nothing to do with jQuery). For some sites, I've dealt with the problem entirely within the CSS, using a combination of the "genuine" rules, the browser-specific versions, and then the [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) htc file (for IE). An example:

```
div.roundbox {
  border-radius: 8px;          // Official. Maybe someday.
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;  // Webkit browsers
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;     // Firefox
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);      // IE
}
```

CSS3 PIE works remarkably well, and seems to perform much better than the IE7.js family of solutions. Basically, you drop that same `behavior` line into any CSS rules that use border-radius, box-shadow, etc. The script takes care of the rest, and has no effect on non-IE browsers that will render the effects via one of the first three directives.

You could also assemble a list of all your PIE-worthy objects and declare the behavior in one shot (after the regular rules):

```
div.shadowbox, div.roundbox, p.somethingelse { behavior: url(PIE.htc); }
```

There is certainly plenty of room for debate about the wisdom of this approach -- but it does work very well in many cases.

Comment: PIE.htc is in essence yet another external javascript library and in beta stage on top on that. My site is very complex and non-standart and this is exactly the kind of solution I want to avoid. I don't even use -webkit and -moz extensions as they tend to have strange unconsitencies sometimes. But thanks for sharing that anyway it looks good!

Comment: Indeed, plenty of room for debate. If you use jQuery, you're already using a 3rd-party library to help smooth over browser differences. Things like rounded corners and box shadow already put you in the realm of strange inconsistency from browser to browser. There's no magic solution for browsers that predate the popular emergence of these effects. Whether you consider pie.htc or some other approach, spackle is spackle. If it works well -- and this does, even on big apps with complex UIs -- then it's as worthy of consideration as any other option. The perfect can be the enemy of the good.

Comment: The reason I want jQuery is exactly this. I already use it for other things. It is proven and will be updated and supported in the future. Another JS library will mean another file to download, another library to care about. It is a matter of principle. If you go this path, the site quickly becomes a mess. If something is non standard I rather not use it.